# why is button toggle not working with class?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When I change my button toggle from ID-Name to Class-Name, the function is not working anymore. Does anyone know why?

I need a class since this button is multiple times on the page and loads in separately via css and sliders. The function and content is still the same.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.infoBtn').on('click', function () {
  var text=$('.infoBtn').text();
  if(text === "info"){
    $(this).html('close');
  } else{
    $(this).text('info');
 }
});
});
```

Comment: That suggests that your `button` does not have the class `infoBtn`. Also you should use `this` more consistently inside the click. Like `var text=$(this).text();`.

Comment: all of them have the class. I have checked.

Comment: Your code should use `$(this)`, not `$('.infoBtn')` inside the handler. What you have now will get the text only from the *first* one on the page.

Comment: Funny when you do it correctly when you set the text, but not when you read the text. Reading the text you are always looking at the page for the first button with the class, not the one that was clicked. `var text = $('.infoBtn').text();` should be `var text=$(this).text()`

Comment: I tried what you said, Pointy but its not working with this. I put (this) twice, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your use of selector inside the click event:

```
$('.infoBtn').text();
```

> Pointy:
> Your code should use `$(this)`, not `$('.infoBtn')` inside the handler.
> What you have now will get the text only from the *first* one on the
> page.

If you change that to `$(this)`, it should work as required:

```
$(this).text();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.infoBtn').on('click', function(){
    //REM: Use $(this) and not $('.infoBtn')!
    let text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text((text === 'info') ? 'close' : 'info')
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class = 'infoBtn'>initial</button>
<button class = 'infoBtn'>initial</button>
```

Comment: for refining the code a `ternary conditional operator` would be appropriate here and shorten the code: `$(this).text((text === 'info') ? 'close' : 'info')`

Comment: I am glad it works now. I consider this a typo question and you should just delete it.

Comment: While questions with this "error" happens a lot, I would not consider it a typo question

Comment: Alright, in that case I am going to edit it a bit to point out the actual error.

Comment: I still don't know why it did not work in first place. when I used it with the id it worked out. but only checked one button, not the others...

Comment: Because the `id` must be unique and therefore only selects the first element with that `id`. So `$(#id)` would likely select the same element as `$(this)`, for there being just one with it. While having multiple buttons with the same class `$('.infoBtn').text()` always provides the text of the first match, not the text of the actually clicked element. `$(this).text()` provides the text of the element which was clicked. You can observe it by adding a `console.log(text)` below your `var text` assignment.